# different represent of HTML in firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am confused with: this code daemon display different in Firefox and Chrome:

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;"> 
    <a href="baidu.com" >AA<span style="float:right">BB</span></a>
</div>
```

```css
a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    white-space: nowrap;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/ChinaXing/pen/jwFon

In Chrome:

> [image: In Chrome]

In Firefox:

> [image: In Firefox]

Comment: Looks same, both in `firefox` and `chrome`. Please tell what difference are you facing or better provide screenshot.

Comment: delete `white-space: nowrap;` and it looks the same

Comment: @Rahil Wazir the BB isn´t in the same line as AA

Comment: I don't know why, only how to fix. Move the bb to the start, like this: <span style="float:right">BB</span>AA

Comment: @Igoel oh yeah i didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the style 'white-space: nowrap'

AABB

```
 a {
    padding: 3px 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border:1px solid red;
}
span {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align:left; overflow:hidden;` to the anchor tag